# How to filter selected column with even numbers?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe as below and wanted to filter only column "B" with even numbers.

```
    A   B   C   D

0   9   15  64  28

1   93  29  8   73

2   40  36  16  11

3   88  62  33  72

4   49  51  54  77
```

Required Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
2   40  36  16  11
3   88  62  33  72
```

Comment: Where are the new B values coming from? I thought you needed only to filter rows

Answer (score 2):

Just use modulo math like the below:

```
df[df['B'] % 2 == 0]
```

And now printing `df` would give the expected dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.B % 2 == 0]
```

output :

```
    A   B   C   D
2   40  36  16  11
3   88  62  33  72
```